# use local path for fonts in less

Tags: css, fonts, less

I am trying to use a server local path in the less css pre-processor to fonts to speed up page loading (pulling from fonts.googleapis.com can take 300ms).

Using this path works:

```
@web-font-path: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700";
```

I tried changing to a local path:

```
@web-font-path: "../../fonts/Roboto";
```

Then using the path:

```
.web-font(@path) {
  @import url("@{path}");
}
.web-font(@web-font-path);
```

However after changing to local when I compile this with webpack I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./stylesheets/less/index.less
Module build failed: variable @path is undefined
near lines:
.web-font(@web-font-path);
```

Somehow @path variable works with a web url (less seems to work out that @path is related to @web-font-path as I dont define @path anywhere), but not with a local url.

I am compiling .less files using webpack with the following in mt webpack.config.js module: section:

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    include: INPUT_DIR,
    loader: 'style!css!less',
  },
```

NB I also tried a test of:

```
@web-font-path: "../../fonts/Roboto";
@import url(@web-font-path);
```

But I get the following error from webpack (I have no Roboto.less fle, Roboto is a directory containg .eot,.woff,.svg files) :

```
Module build failed: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../fonts/Roboto.less
```

With the following code:

```
@web-font-path: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700";
@import url(@web-font-path);
```

I get this error:

```
Module build failed: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined
 @ undefined (line undefined, column undefined)
```

Comment: `@import` statements are evaluated before mixins so it's not going to work this way (i.e. the error is not in the path but in the mixin itself).

Comment: @seven-phases-max The path works OK when it is https just not local

Comment: See [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40web-font-path%3A%20%5C%22it%20does%20not%20matter%5C%22%3B%5Cn%5Cn.web-font(%40path)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40import%20url(%5C%22%40%7Bpath%7D%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.web-font(%40web-font-path)%3B%22%7D). I does not matter what's actually in the `@web-font-path` (yet again because imports are evaluated before mixins, so mixin parameters do not even exist at this point - hence `variable @path is undefined`).

Comment: So to find out if the new path is working or not at all you'll need at first get rid of `.web-font(@web-font-path);` (as it's not going to work this way) and try `@import url(@web-font-path);` instead.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I tried what I think you mean and appended to the question but still not compiling.

Comment: To clarify. If you change the string to "foo.css" in my example above it actually will compile (it actually *do* work in recent Less versions this way because it translates to a plain [CSS import] so compiler is able to resolve the variable via some tricks). While your second "../../fonts/Roboto"; link is a link a Less file. That the first problem.

Comment: The second problem is that "I have no Roboto.less fle, Roboto is a directory containg .eot,.woff,.svg files" - `@import`s do not work with such things. The imported file shall be either CSS or Less file (open https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700 link in your browser to see it's actually a CSS file). So you'll resolve both 1 and 2 errors by actually having a copy of it as "Roboto.css".

Comment: And the third problem is that the CSS files served by `fonts.googleapis.com` are *browser depended* (so by creating its local copy you may have some troubles with exotic browser(s) - i.e. IE). So for its local copy to work exactly as the remote one you'll need to look at all possible versions of it the server may return, just to not miss any possible browser depended tricks (after all they may point to different font binaries for each browser) they could use).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Please add the last few comments as an answer and I will accept as solved.

Comment: Your post is lacking fairly important information. Can you please explain in your post when and how you're invoking the less compiler: offline CLI invocation, on-page `less.js` (which would be incredibly bad), wrapped by a bundler like webpack or the like, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added a note on compilation to the post (using webpack)